# Grab files from desktop and add to my website like in Google Drive

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Is there any way to create a page on my website where I can put in one time few files from my computer, the same as it works in Google Drive? Any tools, ideas how it works? I am working with .NET MVC.

Comment: You want to upload the files to google drive or you want to store them on your web server?

Comment: On my website, the same way as it is made in Google Drive

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on this, try this one for example - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-form-with-file-upload/

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/